# Criteria api expression with cast

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, expression, predicate

I'm new with jpa, need something like this:

```
TypedQuery<XXX> typedQuery = em.createQuery("select c from XXX c where cast(c.description as string) like :name", XXX.class);
typedQuery.setParameter("name", startStr + "%");
```

I'm using "cast" because c.description has an unusual type (type "mvarchar" in postgresql patch for 1c). This works but I have to use predicates:

```
ParameterExpression<String> parameter = builder.parameter(String.class, "name");
predicate = builder.like(root.<String>get("description"), parameter);    
query.where(builder.and(predicate));
```

"description" has String type in XXX entity class.

Error after execution:
ERROR: operator does not exist: mvarchar ~~ character varying

I tried to make "as" (root.get("description").as(String.class)), but result is the same.

Can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a custom dialect to register mvarchar type as a nvarchar.

```
public class MyDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, 255, "mvarchar($l)");
}
```

If this way you force Hibernate to think as a mvarchar column as a standard varchar.

Comment: I've got the same result as before: operator does not exist: mvarchar ~~ character varying

Comment: Did you substitute in persistence.xml the new dialect?

Comment: Yes, i changed dialect

Comment: After changes first variant ("select c from XXX c where cast(c.description as string) like :name") gives me same error (mvarchar ~~ character varying). It looks like mvarchar cannot be used with "like" operator. I need  convert it to string.